# Is the category of simple graphs finitely complete?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

I have read (on nLab and wikipedia) three conflicting statements:

1. The category of simple graphs is finitely complete
2. The category of simple graphs has no terminal object
3. A category is finitely complete if and only if it has a terminal objects and pullbacks.

I am pretty sure (2) is true, but I don't know which, if either of (1) and (3) is true.  I am also curious about whether the category of finite simple graphs is finitely complete.

Thanks!

Comment: A terminal object is a limit of the empty diagram and thus is a finite limit. However you also need pullbacks for a category to have all finite limits. So (3) is only in one direction. Also we see (1) and (2) are contradictory.

Comment: Since a lonely vertex with no arrows is simple and a vertex with a loop (the terminal object in the category of directed graphs) is not simple, you are correct that the category of simple graphs has no terminal object. So we have only (2) as the correct statement. However, it is worth looking at constructing binary products and possibly pullbacks.

Comment: Not including pullbacks in (3) was just a mistake (now fixed).  Just to be clear, we are saying that the category of simple graphs is not finitely complete (because it has no terminal object).  Here is the source of my confusion: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+simple+graphs  It appears to say that the category is regular, which implies finitely complete.

Comment: I can't seem to read nlab's page on my iphone. My guess is that they are using a slightly different definition of a simple graph. Probably they require a loop for each vertex. Then I think the the lonely vertex with a single loop is terminal in the category. In fact I think this defn of simple graph makes the category reflective in the category of graphs. The reflector just identifies all arrow to one and adds necessary loops. But I need to check this. Anyway, what is your defn of simple graphs?

Comment: With the correction, (3) is now correct.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the nLab and the wikipedia are talking about different categories.

As Rachmaninoff pointed out, the nLab is using as definition of simple graph a set $V$ equipped with a reflexive and symmetric relation. The point is that "adding the missing loops" produces a bijection between simple graph structures on $V$ (in the graph-theorist’s sense) and reflexive and symmetric relations on $V$.

However, the categories are not equivalent. A vertex with a loop is a terminal object in $SimpleGraphs_{nLab}$ while $SimpleGraphs$ does not have a terminal object. The functor "add the missing loops" fails to be full.

Comment: When I took a graph theory course as an undergraduate both categories were mentioned (but the word "category" was not). For objects, having loops everywhere or nowhere is of course the same; let's say simple graphs are not allowed to have any loops. Then, in one category the morphisms were called *homomorphisms* in the course I took: functions sending adjacent vertices to adjacent vertices; in the other category the morphisms were called *reflexive homomorphisms*: functions sending to adjacent vertices to vertices that are either adjacent or equal.